# How to add numbers to thumbnails in a jQuery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show numbers on thumbnails, in the slider on my product page.

Problem is, most sliders I've come across, do not have a numbered-thumbnail function. And the few that do, don't support other features I'm looking for.

So, is there a way to add sequential numbers to thumbnails, in a slider that doesn't natively support them?

Comment: You should select a slider, try to implement sequential numbers on it and come back with questions if you run into issues.

Comment: I meant a generic, stand-alone method, that could be used to generate a list of numbered bullets from a list of images.

The "you should select a slider" part is exactly what I'm having a problem with - there are 1000s of sliders out there, and most of them don't have numbered bullets. I was trying to save time vs having to try dozens of sliders and being disappointed every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the normal way sliders work for each page. They usually have some CSS class applied to them. If find that class you can usually make the effect that covers up the number disabled.

[Usual HTML Setup for Sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30aUp.png)
If you are more specific with what slider you are using we can help further.